# Cosa significa "mi sono rotto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Noi, io e gli altri di Occupy Wall Street, andavamo da Fil qualche volta la domenica, nei suoi prati. Lo abbiamo fatto per un po'. E lí sí che mettevamo le tende... A volte ci stavamo anche una settimana. Tanto era una tenuta cosí grande... Solo che poi, sai cosa? Tutte quelle pecore, sinceramente, a me stavano un po' sulle palle. Va bene schierarsi, però poi Fil si era schierato troppo, secondo me. Cioè, le pecore se le poteva anche risparmiare. Io alla fine *mi sono rotta*. Andavo da lui, ma le pecore no grazie. Quando lui doveva pascolare o riordinare l'ovile, lo aspettavo in casa.

Non capisco cosa significa "mi sono rotta" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

È lo stesso che *mi sono seccata*, nel senso di *perdere la pazienza nell'aspettare/fare qualcosa*.

Più precisamente, come riporta il vocabolario [*Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rompere/) alla voce **a.**:

> In alcune espressioni di tono volg., talvolta eufemistiche in luogo di altre più crude, **seccare**, **annoiare**, **infastidire** o **molestare**: *r. i coglioni, le palle, e r. i corbelli, gli zebedei, le scatole, le tasche, gli stivali; mi hai rotto le scatole!; r. l’anima,*.

o, ancora, secondo [*Il Corriere*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/rompere.shtml) (voce **1**):

> volg., *le palle, i coglioni a qlcu.*, **infastidirlo**, **importunarlo**.

È equivalente all'[inglese](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sick+of) *(to) get sick of...*:

> **sick (and tired) of somebody/something**:
>   **annoyed** by someone or something, **fed up** (with somebody/something) *They visited so often that she was sick of them by the end of the summer*. *I'm sick and tired of hearing the same old excuses!*
>   Usage notes: usually said about something that you have accepted for too long.

---

*Edit:* come suggerito da @MauroVanetti una forma molto utilizzata - la stessa dell'esempio riportato dall'autrice del post - è quella abbreviata *[mi sono rotto/a](https://twitter.com/hashtag/misonorotta?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)*, in cui l'oggetto è sottinteso. Il significato è il medesimo delle espressioni sopra riportate, ma l'essenzialità della stessa espressione tende a comunicare una sensazione di assolutezza.

Comment: Giusto, l'aspetto che sottolineerei nella tua risposta è che questa espressione è come _Mi sono rotta le scatole_ ma omettendo le scatole (o peggio), negli esempi che hai citato dalla Treccani e dal Corriere non si menziona questa possibilità che invece è molto utilizzata, anche se ha ancora una leggera coloritura giovanile.

Comment: @MauroVanetti, concordo in pieno e ti ringrazio per la puntualizzazione. :)

Comment: Secondo me, sarebbe interessante aggiungere la precisazione da @MauroVanetti alla risposta. Conoscevo il significato di "mi sono rotto le scatole" o simili, ma non sapevo che "mi sono rotto" significasse lo stesso.

Comment: Ricevuto ed editato. Grazie per il suggerimento. :)